# How to get input value on button click?

Tags: jquery

Here is the form code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form_id" action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" name="fields_email" class="email_field">
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="Subscribe" class="subscribe_btn">
</form>
```

JS file :

```
$('.subscribe_btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log( $("#form_id .email_field").val() );        
});
```

How to get the live input value? On click i'm getting old value NOT live....

Thank You, 
Dmitry

Comment: What you have should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/WWuXw/

Comment: [Your code works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/n97JM/)

Comment: it is working as expected check here: http://jsfiddle.net/jD45T/ or else can you edit and tell what do you expect

Comment: There is only the LIVE value.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mbker/ and what do you mean "live" ?

Comment: Yeah works there http://jsfiddle.net/WWuXw/ , after I refresh the page I type something and click submit and I get old value... Seems like code is fine, need to check my code. Thanks guys

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

```
$('.subscribe_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($("#form_id .email_field").val());

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhqC7/

I just changed console to `alert()`, tested in both FF9.0.1, IE8, Chrome 16.0.X

Comment: This is something you should post as a comment (as the others have), not an answer.

Comment: I'm using this code in light box pop up, and getting old value, weird

Comment: @DmitryT, please post more details, browser, jQuery version, etc; we are guessing here and just getting downvoted for our guesses ... wait.. lightbox popup? Is it iframed by chance? You never mentioned lightbox before.

Comment: yes, it doesnt work for me in all browsers, i'm using jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js, will post code in sec